# Load balancing in Jboss EAP 6 or JBOSS AS 7.1.2 with Mod cluster

Tags: jboss7.x, load-balancing

We have two war files both with same context root deployed on two servers on each host.
The reason for keeping same context root is its a open source war and changing the context root needs some tweaks so we are trying to use the same context roots (However we are open to changing the context root if its a must).

**Below are the host and port names**

```
drhapp05:8085  - IDP  with context root /openam 
drhapp05:8086   - IDPProxy with context root /openam

drhapp06:8085 - IDP  with context root /openam 
drhapp06:8086 - IDPProxy with context root /openam
```

Our goal is that when we access the url
**idpdev.devs1.int** ==> The request should be fwd to IDP running on

```
 
  drhapp05:8085/openam or drhapp06:8085/openam
```

**idpproxydev.devs1.int** ==>The request should be fwd to IDPPRXY running on

```
  drhapp05:8086/openam or drhapp06:8086/openam
```

So we made the following changes as per the documentation at 
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/VirtualHostsWithJBossAS7

**In domain.xml (since we use domain mode)**

```
       <virtual-server name="devidpvs" default-web-module="OAM-IDP-1.0">
            <alias name="idpdev.devs1.int"/>
            <alias name="drhapp05"/>
            <alias name="drhapp06"/>
       </virtual-server>
       <virtual-server name="devproxyvs" default-web-module="OAM-IDPPROXY-1.0">
            <alias name="idpproxydev.devs1.int"/>
            <alias name="drhapp05"/>
            <alias name="drhapp06"/>
       </virtual-server>
```

**In jboss-web.xml in each war**

In the idp version of openam war (OAM-IDP-1.0.war) in jboss-web.xml we

```
        <jboss-web>
           <context-root>openam</context-root>
           <virtual-host>devidpvs</virtual-host>
         </jboss-web>
```

In the idpproxy version of openam war (OAM-IDPPROXY-1.0) in jboss-web.xml we have

```
        <jboss-web>
           <context-root>openam</context-root>
           <virtual-host>devproxyvs</virtual-host>
         </jboss-web>
```

Finally **on modcluster in  httpd.conf** file we  added the following to the httpd.conf file on the webserver:

```
              <VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName idpdev.devs1.int
              </VirtualHost>
              <VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName idpproxydev.devs1.int
              </VirtualHost>
```

This configurtaion doesnt allow both urls to be accessed at same time.

```
If we shut down say 
drhapp05:8086   - IDPProxy 
drhapp06:8086   - IDPProxy 
Then we can access  IDP using url idpdev.devs1.int/openam which forwards the request 
to  drhapp05:8085/openam or drhapp06:8085/openam
and vice-versa.
```

We tried ProxyPass On directive but this redirects the request instead of forwarding the request which is not what we want.
Any thoughts whats wrong with our config ?
Also we were wondering if there is way to specify the port names in domain.xml under alias tag.

-Ram

Answer (score 0):

1. We created new dns names to avoid duplication and updated the domain.xml (or standalone.xml).

   ```
    <virtual-server name="devidpvs" default-web-module="OAM-IDP-1.0">
     <alias name="idpdev.devs1.int"/>
       <alias name="drhapp05_internal"/>
       <alias name="drhapp06_internal"/>
    </virtual-server>
    <virtual-server name="devproxyvs" default-web-module="OAM-IDPPROXY-1.0">
       <alias name="idpproxydev.devs1.int"/>
       <alias name="drhapp05_external"/>
       <alias name="drhapp06_external"/>
    </virtual-server>
   ```

Such that the ip address of
drhapp05_external and drhapp05_internal  match to drhapp05
drhapp06_external and drhapp06_internal  match to drhapp06

1. In httpd.conf we added additonal attribute UseAlias

   ```
          <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerName idpdev.devs1.int
           UseAlias 1   
         </VirtualHost>
         <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerName idpproxydev.devs1.int
           UseAlias 1 
         </VirtualHost>
   ```

We were wondering if there was way to specify the port numbers in domain.xml as way  to ensure uniqueness in domain.xml under .......
Its strange that the host name can be used just once in entire domain.xml.
But anyway for now we are using the above solution and it works.